# Creating Multiple Columns in Hyde Theme for Jekyll

Tags: css, responsive-design, jekyll

I am creating an about us page in Jekyll. I am using [hyde](http://hyde.getpoole.com/) theme which is based on [poole](http://getpoole.com/).

I am trying to add headshots of the people involved with a basic profile about them. The issues is that I am not able to manage that in two columns. I do not know whether that will affect the responsiveness of the website (as I have so far not succeeding in getting two columns side by side).

I tried looking at the source code of poole's website. They used a css class called themes for that. I tried taking that approach but did not succeed in getting a two columns layout.

How can I keep my site responsive to mobile layout and still create a two column layout for content?

**EDIT**: Code for the creation of multiple columns.

```
    <div class = "themes"> // class to create columns
        <div class="circle" style="background-image: url('/public/nitesh.jpg')">
        </div>
    </div>

    <p> Mr. Nitesh Pandey<br> <nitesh.osf@gmail.com> </p>

    <div class  = "themes"> // class to create another column beside the one above.
        <div class="circle" style="background-image: url('/public/parth.jpg')">
        </div>
    </div>

    <p> Mr. Parth Bolke </br> <parth.osf@gmail.com>
```

Comment: Yo! @user112675 what is your question and where is your code ?

Comment: Hello. I realize I should have posted it here. I am extremely sorry. Please find the in the edited part and the link to the live site here.

http://osf.me/1.%20about/

Comment: poole does not provide css grids. If you want to do columns, you need a grid css like [Twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=1673893864b2d591489c) or [Pure](http://purecss.io/grids/) or any css grid framework.

Comment: Right David. I thank you very much for your time. I believe in this case, I would learn how to use [Foundation](http://http://foundation.zurb.com) and recreate this template in Foundation for Jekyll. 

If you have a suggestion for me, please do let me know. 
Thank you once again.